# OpenAPI with Spring Data Rest

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, spring-data-rest, springdoc-openapi-ui

In my project, All the endpoints are exposed by Spring Data Rest. I don't have the service and controller layer.
I have the required dependencies for Spring data rest and OpenApi support.
In the repository, CRUD methods are annotated as follows.

```
@Operation(summary = "Get Person based on Id passed as parameter")
    @RestResource(exported = true)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not Found"), @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error") })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    Optional<Person> findById(@Parameter(name="UUID") @RequestParam("UUID") @PathVariable Integer id);
```

In the Swagger UI, the description for the id, Operation Summary and any other props are not getting reflected.
Since I don't have RestControllers, is there a way to customize these things for endpoints exposed by the Spring data rest?